# PHP+Dropbox, Get Thumbnail Via CURL returns on first bit of larger thumbnails

Tags: php, curl, dropbox-api

I'm using CURL in PHP to get Thumbnails from Dropbox. This is working and displaying images. It's working perfectly with smaller than 64x64 but anything larger is only returning top part of the image. Not sure if its CURL or something else but it's like there is a cap on the amount of data at one point. Does CURL limit that data and is there a way around it or is a variable limiting it or what could be the issue?

```
$cSession = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,
    "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_thumbnail");
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$headers = array('Authorization: Bearer ,<key>',
    'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path": "id:<fileId>",'.
    '"format": "png","size": "w128h128","mode": "bestfit"}');
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($cSession);
curl_close($cSession);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));
echo  $result;
exit;
```

[image: Request for 64x64]
[image: Request for 128x128]
[image: Request for 256x256]

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue

```
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));
```

was limiting the output. Removing it fixed the issue.